# Comparing print statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i am trying to do is to make an Overall result for example: if Order Number + Hardware Version + Software Version + Mac address + Device type "PASS" then overall result "PASS" should be printed if even one of them "FAIL" then the overall result should print "FAIL" and should print what failed for example the Hardware version.
I hope you guys understand what i am trying to do, i will write a kind of pseudo code to explain what i am trying to figure out.

1. If Order Number = PASS + Hardware Version = PASS + Software Version = PASS + Mac address = PASS + Device type = PASS
   then Overall result = print("Overall Result PASS")
2. If even one Field is "FAIL"  for example:
   if Order Number = FAIL + Hardware Version = PASS + Software Version = PASS + Mac address = PASS + Device type = PASS
   then Overall result = print("Overall Result FAIL", "Order Number FAIL")
3. If Order Number = FAIL + Hardware Version = FAIL + Software Version = PASS + Mac address = PASS + Device type = PASS
   then Overall result = print("Overall Result FAIL", "Order Number FAIL", "Hardware Version FAIL")

4... and so on

I am trying to implement this function but I really do not know how to go about it, please go easy on me folks i just started programming would be nice if someone could show me a sample code of how this function can be made and suggestions are much appreciated too.

```
# Order number
print("Desired Order number:",d_ordernum)
print("Order number from scancode :",scan_code_cropped_artikel)
print("Ordernumber from wbm: ", ord_nmr)
if d_ordernum == ord_nmr == scan_code_cropped_artikel:
    print("Order number PASS")
else:
    print("FAIL")
print(100*"")

# Hardware version
print("Desired Hardware Version:",d_hw_version)
print("Hardware Version from wbm: ", v)
if d_hw_version == v:
    print("Hardware version PASS")
else:
    print("Wrong Hardware Version")
print(100*"")

# Software version
print("Desired Software Version:",d_sf_version)
print("Software Version from wbm: ", b)
if d_sf_version == b:
    print("Software version PASS")
else:
    print("FAIL")
print(100*"")

# Mac address
print("Mac address from scancode :",scan_code_cropped_mac)
print("Mac address from wbm: ", mac_addr)
list_of_chars = mac_addr.split(":")
mac_address_string_joined = ''.join(list_of_chars) 
if scan_code_cropped_mac == mac_address_string_joined:
    print("PASS")
else:   
    print("FAIL")
print(100*"")
# Product Code
d_product_code = pc_praefix + "-" + d_sf_version + "-" + d_hw_version
product_code = pc_praefix + "-" + b + "-" + v
print("Desired product code: ",d_product_code )
print("Product code of current device: ", product_code)
print(100*"")


#Device type
print("Desired device type:",d_dev_typ)
print("Device type from wbm: ", dev_typ)
if d_dev_typ == dev_typ:
    print("PASS")
else:
    print("FAIL")
print(100*"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just need some code to enhance the functionality of the one you have in your question, you can do something like maintaining a flag to decide whether to output an overall pass or fail and a list to hold the statuses that you want to output.

Here is an example of how to manipulate the list of statuses (you can tweak it to suit your needs):

```
OVERALL_STATUS = 1
STATUS_LIST = []

# Order number
print("Desired Order number:",d_ordernum)
print("Order number from scancode :",scan_code_cropped_artikel)
print("Ordernumber from wbm: ", ord_nmr)
if d_ordernum == ord_nmr == scan_code_cropped_artikel:
    print("Order number PASS")
else:
    print("FAIL")
    OVERALL_STATUS = 0
    STATUS_LIST.append('Order Number FAIL')
print(100*"")

# Hardware version
print("Desired Hardware Version:",d_hw_version)
print("Hardware Version from wbm: ", v)
if d_hw_version == v:
    print("Hardware version PASS")
else:
    print("Wrong Hardware Version")
    OVERALL_STATUS = 0
    STATUS_LIST.append('Order Number FAIL')
print(100*"")

if OVERALL_STATUS:
    print('Overall Result PASS')
else:
    print('Overall Result FAIL, ' + ', '.join(STATUS_LIST))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then try to write something like this:

```
def my_func(d_ordernum, scan_code_cropped_artikel, ord_nmr):
    my_list = [d_ordernum, scan_code_cropped_artikel, ord_nmr]
    if 'FAIL' in my_list and 'PASS' in my_list:
        print('d_ordernum = {}\n'
              'scan_code_cropped_artikel = {}\n'
              'ord_nmr = {}'.format(d_ordernum, scan_code_cropped_artikel, ord_nmr))
    if 'FAIL' in [d_ordernum, scan_code_cropped_artikel, ord_nmr]:
        print('One or more FAIL')
```

Then follow the same logic

Answer (score 1):

One more way of solving.

You can maintain a dictionary whether it is PASS/ FAIL. If it is PASS then value is True else False.

```
mapping = {"d_order_num": False, "d_hw_version": False,
           "d_sf_version": False, "mac_addr_matched": False,
           "d_dev_typ": False}


def check_all_matches():
    if all(mapping.values()):
        print("PASS. All matched")
    else:
        print("FAIL")


# Order number
print("Desired Order number:", d_ordernum)
print("Order number from scancode :", scan_code_cropped_artikel)
print("Ordernumber from wbm: ", ord_nmr)
if d_ordernum == ord_nmr == scan_code_cropped_artikel:
    mapping["d_order_num"] = True

# Hardware version
print("Desired Hardware Version:", d_hw_version)
print("Hardware Version from wbm: ", v)
if d_hw_version == v:
    mapping["d_hw_version"] = True

# Software version
print("Desired Software Version:", d_sf_version)
print("Software Version from wbm: ", b)
if d_sf_version == b:
    mapping["d_sf_version"] = True

# Mac address
print("Mac address from scancode :", scan_code_cropped_mac)
print("Mac address from wbm: ", mac_addr)
list_of_chars = mac_addr.split(":")
mac_address_string_joined = ''.join(list_of_chars)
if scan_code_cropped_mac == mac_address_string_joined:
    mapping["mac_addr_matched"] = True


# Device type
print("Desired device type:", d_dev_typ)
print("Device type from wbm: ", dev_typ)
if d_dev_typ == dev_typ:
    mapping["d_dev_typ"] = True


check_all_matches()
```